# Best way to avoid stale *.pyc files?

Tags: python, git, version-control

What's the best way to avoid stale *.pyc files? Sometimes, especially when switching branches in version control, some *.pyc files are left there and are used by Python instead of the source files I have.

What's the best strategy for making sure I don't create or unknowingly use stale *.pyc files?

Comment: how about gitignore `.pyc` ?

Comment: @Raptor - if you run the python modules in your repo directory instead of copying or installing them elsewhere, you get the .pyc's quite regardless of gitignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a useful environment variable for that: [PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE)

```
export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=true
```

Comment: All good answers. This seems to be the only method whereby I never have to think about *.pyc files again.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to khampson, git and mercurial (and likely others) allow client side hooks. You can sprinkle around scripts that do

```
find -iname "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

on linux at least. Search "git hooks" and "mercurial hooks" for more details.

Comment: `find -name '*.pyc' -delete`

Comment: @DietrichEpp - good point. Does `-delete` work with non-writable files and etc... like `rm` with the force flag?

Comment: Probably not, but I don't expect that to be a problem.  Note that you may want to use `rm -f -- {} +` if you go the `rm` route.  The `--` prevents arguments from being interpreted as flags, and `+` causes `find` to batch calls to `rm`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a combined approach.

First, add `*.pyc` to your **.gitignore** file, which should help to avoid issues when switching branches (at least for cases where the cause is that a .pyc file somehow got committed). I generally always add both `*.pyc` and `*.log` to my **.gitignore** so as not to potentially commit any of those files accidentally, and so they don't clutter my `git status` output.

Second, create a wrapper shell script which first *removes* all `.pyc` files (recursively if your source directory structure calls for it) and then invokes your actual script. That should ensure any resulting `.pyc` files are newly created using the current source.

i.e. something like (without the `&` if you want the script to wait):

```
#!/bin.sh
rm -f *.pyc
./foo.py &
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be `imp.reload()`. I think in 2.7 you can do the following (will check later)

```
>>> import sys
>>> reload(sys)
  <module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>>
```

The disadvantage of this method is that versions of your *.pyc files would still be on the repository and updated every time there is a commit. However it would safeguard you from stale versions of *.pyc.

Another solution would be to make git ignore *.pyc files as well as delete them. Another solution would be to ignore the **pycache** directory. From the book by [Mark Lutz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449355730):

> In 3.2 and later, Python instead saves its .pyc byte code files in a
>   subdirectory named
>   **pycache** located in the directory where your source files reside, and in files whose names identify the Python version that created them
>   (e.g., script.cpython-33.pyc). The new **pycache** subdirectory helps
>   to avoid clutter, and the new naming convention for byte code files
>   prevents different Python versions installed on the same computer from
>   overwriting each other’s saved byte code.